# Deleting newline while reporting into a file with grep and shell script

Tags: ubuntu, grep, sh, markdown, newline

I am reading some values from multiple files, then I append them into a ***markdown*** file in order to create a table. Searched parameters may not appear which means empty spot for the given row/column. My problem is when I acquire a value via ***grep***, it automatically returns with `\n`. I tried to use `tr -d "\n"` approach, simply I could not manage while writing at the same time. 
Let me share with you what I have.

```
printf "|" >> Services | grep -r "Restart" $filename >> Services.md 
printf "|" >> Services | grep -r "WantedBy" $filename >> Services.md | printf "|\n"
```

Intended return format is:

```
1:|Restart...|WantedBy...|  
2:|Restart...|WantedBy...|
3:|Restart...|WantedBy...|
```

Yet, I have:

```
1:|Restart...
||
2:||WantedBy...|
3:|Restart...
|WantedBy...|
```

Would you enlighten me about how to tackle such situations?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should add `| tr -d '\n'` after the end of grep parameters and just before `>> Services.md`

Comment: I came up with: 
`printf "|" >> Services | echo -n $(grep -r "Restart=" $filename) >> Services
printf "|" >> Services | echo -n $(grep -r "WantedBy=" $filename) >>Services
printf "|\n" >> Services`